# Milky way Photograph with Point and shoot?

Tags: camera-settings, astrophotography, point-and-shoot, milky-way, mountain

Well the title keeps hardly anything for you to imagine.

I'll be going to the Mountains in a few months and love to click when I feel like. So, was wondering, is it possible to capture the Night sky (milky way) with a point and shoot I have? If so, any tips/tricks/ways/pointers to do so?

BTW, I have the Sony Cybershot DSC H100.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the highest ISO setting it allows. What is the longest exposure time your camera allows at the highest ISO?

Comment: ISO 3200, F/3.1, 30 seconds

Comment: Don't forget a sturdy tripod and use the timer release. Have fun!

Comment: thank you for the response! I have bought a dslr recently; hope to try it out for milky way soon. didn't get to view the milky way in my first trek.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read this article on [taking shots of the Milky Way](http://www.lonelyspeck.com/how-to-make-an-amazing-photo-of-the-milky-way-galaxy/).

Just to pick out one specific example, they show a shot taken with a Canon T2i ("a much older model" DSLR) and the Canon 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 (basic kit lens). I set it to 18mm and f/3.5, shot a 30 second exposure at ISO 6400.

Now note this is a DSLR (larger sensor).

The exposure required a long exposure (30 seconds is typically the longest you can do without a Bulb mode on your camera) and very high ISO (ISO 6400).  I'd consider that the high ISO seriously compromises what you could do with a P&S, which have small sensors and hence extremely high noise at high ISO.

To lower ISO you need to use a wider aperture (again, not an option for a P&S) and/or use a longer exposure (not really an option for a P&S even with bulb mode, as it increase noise more).

If you really want to do that, consider buying (or borrowing) a *used* older model DSLR and a basic kit lens (like an 18-55) and read that article to see how to proceed from that.

Now you can *try* and use the P&S to take the shot, but I'd not expect much and I'd suggest you try a night time shot of the sky in a park or similar before taking you trip to get a feel for what's going to happen.